# How does the addSharedElement api that was added to FragmentTransaction work?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

Api 21 has added an api called `addSharedElement` that looks like it is supposed to be used similar to shared views with activity transitions, see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addSharedElement(android.view.View, java.lang.String))

I attempted to use this api by setting `android:transitionName` on a view in both fragments and then calling `addSharedElement` on the `FragmentTransaction`. On the fragment, I called `setSharedElementEnterTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());`.

However, this has no effect.

I am running this on the Lollipop preview that was released earlier this month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The api addSharedElement(view, name) will match the View view in the exiting Fragment (it can have any non-null transitionName) with a View in the entering Fragment with the transitionName name. This allows you to have different transitionNames from the leaving Fragment and the entering Fragment.

This is a common use case when you have several Views that can be shared elements in a Fragment. For example, a list of images on your device. When you click on one, it replaces the Fragment with a new one that has a detailed View or single image View. The list will give each image a transitionName unique to the item. This could be the row id or content URI, for example. In the single-image view, the transitionName could be constant. Let's say it is "largeImage." You could match them up easily:

```
fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(imageIcon, "largeImage");
```

Comment: How can I add multiple shared elements to a fragment transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the shared element transition with a TransitionSet that consists of both ChangeImageTransform and ChangeBounds.